# Why power of two for systems sizes in numerics

Tags: numeric, montecarlo

This could be a very trivial question. I often see in the literature that the system sizes are chosen in a numerical calculation as a power of two. For example, for a Monte Carlo simulation on a spin lattice, the lattice size is often chosen as 2^4=16, 2^5=32, 2^6=64, etc.

Is there a particular scientific reason behind that (something related to binary operation or storage)? Or has it become merely a matter of convention?

Comment: There are numerous algorithms which work best with power of 2 array sizes, particularly the recursive divide-and-conquer type, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't grab the 'obvious reasons'. Would you mind to elaborate a little?

Comment: Divide and conquer algorithms, such as binary search, FFT, etc, keep dividing the data set by a factor of 2, hence a data set which is a power of 2 in size avoids having to deal with odd sized subsets as the data is reduced.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR . You provide some satisfactory explanation though I had wished many people would have come up with answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is not one big universal reason for this, but rather a number of small things that have led to people liking it and getting used to it.

- As already said by @PaulR in the comments, there are a number of algorithms that prefer power of two sizes, most notably recursive [divide and conquer algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm), where a power of two size guarantees that one can divide till the very end without ever running into an uneven number of elements. Two extremely important examples here are the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).
- Using power of two problem sizes it is super convenient and always possible to double or halve them, which makes testing how an algorithm or your implementation of it scales. I often double the problem size and then check how much longer it takes to solve it. If it takes twice as long it looks linear, four times longer seems to be quadratic and 25x longer should be somewhere in between O(n^4) and O(n^5). Note that this might not actually reproduce the theoretical scaling for infinite problem sizes as you might for example have an O(n^3) component with a small prefactor hiding behind an O(n^2) part that dominates for small problem size.
- [Vector instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) are an important ingredient in writing efficient code and the vector sizes are as far as I have ever seen always powers of two, e.g. 4 floats in [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), 8 floats in [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), and hardware manufacturers will probably keep doubling it in the [future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512). By using powers of two you can be quite sure that the vector width always divides your problem size, which might give you a tiny bit of performance or might also just be convenient in case you have not implemented the edge cases yet.

There are probably more reasons but those are just the ones from the top of my head. Which ones apply to your spin system Monte Carlo simulation is implementation dependent, but I would guess that it is only the second one if you are using single spin flip [Metropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm).

Given that it might sometimes have some small advantages and in general is just convenient, you might as well ask if there is a good reason not to use power of two problem sizes. One good reason is definitely to test your edge cases, but other than that I can't really think of one ...